# Getting a 'flat' array out of Doctrine 2 queryBuilder with addSelect

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm wondering if there's a clean way to get around this little conundrum...  Been getting around it, but finally have time to look into "the right way"!

**Doctrine Query Builder Snippet**

```
public function getSprockets(array $id_list, $include_stats = false )
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('p')
        ->from( 'Entity\Foo', 'p' )
        ->where('p.id IN ( :pids )')
        ->setParameter('pids', $id_list);

    if( $include_stats )
        $qb->addSelect( '(SELECT SUM( a.value ) FROM Entity\Stats a WHERE a.foo_id = p.id AND a.type="bar" ) AS bar_count' );

    $res = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
    return $res;
}
```

As is, this snippet behaves very differently whether **addSelect** is invoked or no.  If it is not there, I get a nice flat array as is expected.  If the addSelect is however used (`$include_stats` is true), a row in $res is quite different, containing:

- the entity's parts in a `$row[0]`
- and the addSelect result at the base of the $row, e.g., $row['bar_count']

I realize that listing the columns in ->select('p.id, p.that, p.this') ... gets around the problem, but I don't want to have to maintain these many queries each time the schemata is changed.

Is there a convenient-or-built-in way to get a flat array out of getArrayResult?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve this?